# Is there a way to make changes to the titlebar with GTK2?

Tags: ruby, titlebar, gtk2

I have a desktop application written in Ruby that is using GTK2. It's just a small test application to play with GTK2, but I'm having problems achieving what I want to do. Is there any way using GTK2 to get at the titlebar (apart from setting the title), specifically to either add a button to it (beside the min/max/etc, B in the below diagram) or to add an option to the menu that pops up when you click the icon on the titlebar (A in the below diagram)?

[image]

I'm thinking there might not be because GTK is meant to work with many many different window managers, but I just wondered if there was. As a side question, what event does clicking the 'cross' button fire? At the moment if the user clicks that the window disappears but the program doesn't end - I need to capture that event and quit the program.

Thanks for any help, including hitting me over the head and telling me how silly I am.

Comment: In X11, you don't even know if they're running a WM at all.  What signal the "X" fires depends, also, entirely on the WM -- is this Metacity you're using?

Comment: Chances are it will be, yes. This is (mostly) a one environment program, and that environment is Gnome running on Fedora 13. I can check the default window manager tomorrow, but it's probably metacity.

Comment: Generally the WM owns that area, so you'd have to convince Metacity to draw there (and I don't know that it has any hooks for this).  If you knew this was running in a completely controlled environment, you could probably do something crazy to draw there, but who knows what might break.  :-)

Comment: Hrm. Thanks. I suspected that this might be the case. This is annoying, as all I want to do is add an 'about' to my application, and it's far too small and lonely to use a menu for - there'd be nothing else in the menu. Surely, however, I must be able to hook onto the close button? How else am I meant to make my program finish if the user uses that instead of the quit button I made?

Comment: The window manager will detect when the close button is pressed, there might be a (for instance) global wm-owned keyboard shortcut that does the same thing, which you don't need to know as an application programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the title bar is owned by the window manager and you will typically not have direct access to it.

When the user tries to close the window by clicking the window manager's button, the window will receive the [delete event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event).

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is possible in GTK 3.10 and up, by using `gtk_window_set_titlebar()`. It replaces the window manager's title bar with a custom one. `GtkHeaderBar` is a good custom title bar class to use.

You can't, however, make it look just like the window manager would, because you won't know which window manager the user is running.