# Add a Tool button in titlebar in GTK

Tags: c, gtk, titlebar, gtk2, custom-titlebar

How to add a button (tool) in title bar like maximize and minimize button in title bar.
I need to add help tool button in my window title bar..?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make changes to the titlebar with GTK2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753098/is-there-a-way-to-make-changes-to-the-titlebar-with-gtk2)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the window manager decoration and place some widgets on top of your toplever window, emulating the same behavior.